# OLEDB Source with query parameter fails on 2nd iteration

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS pkg with an OLEDB Data flow task that is within a foreach.  The OLEDB source uses a query that im trying to use with a parameter which gets its value from a variable.
The variable value is changed earlier in the flow.  The first time executing, it works fine, but on the 2nd iteration, I get an error

> Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error"

The statement is `SET @MyVar = ?`
This variable gets used in the final select statement for the Source

Again, it works for one iteration, but not the 2nd (debugger).
If I hard code this value it works every time

Comment: What is the value of  `?` in the first iteration and what is it in the second iteration

Comment: Looking at the variables during debug, its 1 and then 2 and the variable is an Int type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is elsewhere or your problem definition is missing something.

I defined a Foreach Item enumerator that uses values 1 and 2 for the loop.

[image]

I create an OLE Source query that is parameterized to pull the current value.

[image]

Loop 1

[image]

Loop 2

[image]

Comment: I think you're correct, but I found a work-around.  Used a derived column between the source and destination and used the variable to populate the field i needed.  Problem solved.  Strange why it worked fine the other way but only the 1st iteration.